# The list of common GUI elements

Tags: user-interface, naming-conventions, naming, element

I need a glossary with graphical examples of elements accompanied by their (I hope) standardized names.
Is there some centralized resource or every framework/platform out there has it's own naming conventions?

Comment: I fear these conventions may vary depending on the environment / language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relevant controls and their official names are typically listed in the respective Interface Guidelines for each platform:

- For OS X, there's the [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html) which has the "official" names for the Mac platform (see especially the "Controls" chapter).
- For the Windows platform, the Windows UX Interaction Guidelines portion of the MSDN has a [Visual Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn688966.aspx) of controls.

Comment: +1. The MSDN visual index is indeed very handy. Thanks for that.

Comment: Thanks! This is the best answer. 
I find strange Windows UX Interaction Guidelines has absolutely no names of layout components. On the contrary Apple Human Interface Guidelines has it all!

Answer (score 2):

As people have already said, it will vary.  However, when I first made the transition to C#, I simply googled `[element I knew] [language I knew] in [language I didn't know]` and that usually did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

There is no centralized resource.  Different frameworks/platforms can refer to the same elements by different names.  Many concepts in the programmers lexicon are referred to by multiple names.

To answer your question, here are some lists of some common controls in [MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47xcww9x%28VS.80%29.aspx) and [HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).